# Shortest distance between two curves.

Tags: geometry

[image]

Shortest distance will be at that point where the tangents at the curve are parallel .

I found derivative of curve .but after that got stuck .

Comment: Tried $x=0$ Should answer your question with 4

Comment: @TheDeadLegend answer is 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
$$f^{'}(x)=-4x^2(9x^3+3x+2) \text{ and } g^{'}(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$$

Slopes equal at $x=0$.

Now, $f(0)=-6 \text{ and } g(0)=4$

Thus distance between points $(0,-6)$ and $(0,4)$  is $10$.  Thus $\frac{\lambda}{2}=5$

Comment: @miracle173 It is something you need to ask the OP. I've just based my answer on the fact that OP suggested.

Comment: @miracle173 Ever tried making two curves and finding the distance? Start by .. Let's say a circle and a parabola I think you will change your mind then?

Comment: But how many points do you have with parallel tangents. For every point on the parabola  there will be two points on  the circle that will have a tangent parallel to the parabola tangent. Does this change your mind :-) ?

Comment: Why should i consider all the cases? I'm concerned with a single nearest point. Just look at that point. Does it happens to have > 1 parallel tangent on the corresponding curve? @miracle173